# Python3: Having trouble calling on a global variable from a while loop in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and am attempting to call on "i" in my while loop and I declared the variable on line 1. I've read a lot on the call stack, so I thought the order here was okay.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLVNF.png)

I'm getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex33.py", line 14, in <module>
    mathtime()
  File "ex33.py", line 6, in mathtime
    while i < j:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment
```

Any help or pointer in the general direction would be awesome!

Comment: Read some interesting documentation in the FAQ https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html?highlight=global#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to the top of your function:

```py
global i, j
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll read up on global variables.